# Count instances within a date range in AWS Athena

Tags: sql, amazon-web-services, amazon-athena

Trying to query my table to tell me the count of instances of one of my columns appearing over 2 different ETL runs. How I would ask it to give me everything in regards to its harmonized value is

```
SELECT clientname, mdm_cleanse_value_clientname FROM "tablename" WHERE mdm_cleansed_value_clientname IS NULL
```

That would give me what is left to harmonize. Im interested in duplicate values appearing across the next batch, we use metadata_job_start_time as our indicator, so I would need either a TOP or MAX function that includes the top 2 metadata_job_start_time

I am imagining towards the end it would read

```
SELECT metadata_job_run_id, metadata_job_start_time, clientname, COUNT(clientname)
FROM "tablename"
WHERE COUNT(clientname) > 1 
GROUP BY metadata_job_start_time, metadata_job_run_id, clientname
```

How do I put in my date range

Comment: Hint: `COUNT()` is not allowed in a `WHERE` clause.

Comment: SELECT DISTINCT metadata_datasource_name, MAX(metadata_job_start_time) AS "Date", metadata_job_run_id, clientname, COUNT(clientname) >1 AS "Dupliates" FROM "glu-euw1-prd-dat-datasphere-db-transformeddata"."uk_tv_harp" GROUP BY metadata_datasource_name, metadata_job_start_time, metadata_job_run_id, clientname ORDER BY clientname;


This is where I am now and returns a lot of what im looking for, but still too much data. I need it to only give me 2 weeks of data, and i only care where it says "true" under duplicates

Comment: You can use HAVING COUNT(clientname) >1  between GROUP BY and ORDER BY